# How do I analyze journalctl logs outside of journalctl?

Tags: linux, go, systemd

I need to collect some stats from my systemd log files, like how many users pass in a certain query string parameter to my service. I know I can view this information in journalctl but I can't figure out how to do so in Go so that I can aggregate the data. I've been looking for a library for this but can't seem to find anything and I can't figure out where the log files are actually stored.

Comment: Should have mentioned that..I am using Ubuntu.

Comment: If there isn’t a specific Go API for the journal, you could either use the `sd-journal` C API via some Go-C bindings (see `man 3 sd-journal`) or run `journalctl` with a suitable output format (e. g. `journalctl -o json`) and parse that. I’m not sure which option would be preferable.

Comment: systemd questions should get asked over at sibling site https://unix.stackexchange.com/    the entry point is dir /etc/systemd/system in which are subdirs for various services in each subdir are its config files which may or may not contain log config details ... I suggest you figure out how to create a toy systemd service of your own then do battle on viewing its logging where you are starting from a known known

Comment: I viewed it more as a Go question. unix.stackexchange.com doesn't have a Go tag. ;(

Comment: @MarissaLevy it is a binary encoded so you cannot be able to put that in a file. Since it is used to view system logs on linux terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get some clues with projects like:

- [`ChimeraCoder/journalctl-go`](https://github.com/ChimeraCoder/journalctl-go)
- [`eparis/access-daemon`](https://github.com/eparis/access-daemon)
- [`chrissnell/kube-journald-filter`](https://github.com/chrissnell/kube-journald-filter) which uses [`coreos/go-systemd/` `sdjournal` package](https://github.com/coreos/go-systemd/tree/master/sdjournal), with a [Journal class](https://github.com/coreos/go-systemd/blob/b14d3eb023cc860c82b1bb143bb98122d3c40224/sdjournal/journal.go#L315-L316) following the [fields of an actual journal](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.journal-fields.html).
  See the [test class `journal_test.go`](https://github.com/coreos/go-systemd/blob/b14d3eb023cc860c82b1bb143bb98122d3c40224/sdjournal/journal_test.go).

Or you could directly forward it to an external syslog, as in [`pmorton/journalfwd`](https://github.com/pmorton/journalfwd).